# ОШИБКА PHP SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: php, sql

echo '<a href="article.php?id='$row["id"];'">'."show".'';[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Неправильный синтаксис!

```
echo '<a href="article.php?id='.$row["id"].'">show</a>';
```